# Concate text fields with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, concatenation

What is wrong with this query?

```
SELECT gid, (tex1||' '||tex2) AS ident FROM my_table ;
```

The structure of `my_table` is as follow:

```
gid serial NOT NULL
tex1 CHARACTER VARYING(254)
tex2 CHARACTER VARYING(254)
```

The content of `my_table` is:

```
gid | tex1   | tex2
----+--------+--------
1   | A      | dog
2   | Two    | birds
3   | More   | things
```

The result of the query is:

```
gid | ident
----+-------
1   |
2   |
3   |
```

I would have never thought having troubles with such a simple query...

Thanks for help !

Comment: can you please add the error you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the sample data you are providing is correct?

What is the output of: `SELECT gid, (tex1||' '||tex2) IS NULL FROM my_table;`?

It seems that either `tex1` or `tex2` (or both) is `NULL`, thus the concatenation also produces NULL. Use [COALESCE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to provide a non null default value to use in such cases.

```
SELECT
  gid,
  (COALESCE(tex1, '') || ' ' || COALESCE(tex2, '')) AS ident
FROM
  my_table;
```

Comment: That's it... Thank you ! It's always tricky to build up a set of data you are manipulating in order to expose a problem as simply as possible. I just forgot the NULL values and they were the problem!